# Difference between using Arrow function or function for onClick in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, arrow-functions

I built a simple counter app in ReactJS. Code is below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
    const [countNum, setCountNum] = useState(0);

    function increaseCount() {
        setCountNum(countNum + 1);
    }

    function decreaseCount() {
        if (countNum > 0) {
            setCountNum(countNum - 1);
        }
    }

    function disableChecker() {
        if (countNum === 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button onClick={() => decreaseCount()} disabled={disableChecker()}>Decrease</button>
            <button onClick={() => increaseCount()}>Increase</button>
            <h2>{countNum}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I just want to know why does `onClick={() => increaseCount()}` **works** AND why `onClick={increaseCount()}` or `onClick={() => increaseCount}` **doesn't work?**

A beginner here, please guide me to the answer.

Comment: Because one calls the function and passes what it returns as the handler, and the other returns but doesn't call the function when the handler is invoked.

Comment: Also, note that `disabled={countNum === 0}` would be enough, there's no need for a function.

Comment: In JavaScript, a function is invoked by using parentheses `()` following the function name.

Comment: @EmileBergeron thank you for this. Will use this from now on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`onClick={() => increaseCount()}` -> assigns a function as an event handler to `onclick`. The function's body has `increaseCount()` inside it. So when **the function runs** (on event trigger), `increaseCount` is **executed/run**.

`onClick={increaseCount()}` -> React runs `increaseCount` as soon as this **code is encountered**. `increaseCount` changes state and causes a re-render, and in the next render cycle same thing happens causing a cycle. This should have infinite renders.

`onClick={() => increaseCount}` -> Like the first one but here inside the function body, `()` is missing after `increaseCount`. This **does not execute the function**  `increaseCount` when the event happens. **A simple statement with function name without the parentheses will do nothing.**

Comment: so since the arrow function is an asynchronous  function it waits for user to click and executes the function inside it when a click happens but if we pass increaseCount() directly then after clicking it keeps on changing the state and causing infinite loop?

Comment: You do not call a function asynchronous because it runs only when executed right? All functions need to be executed to run. The arrow function is just another function. It will run ON CLICK. In the second case, `increaseCount()` is running everytime because it is directly in the script/code. It is not wrapped in a function at all. The JS engine is just going through the code, and running it. It is being triggered because the OP has written it like that. It is the same as writing `increaseCount()` in the React component body. It will always run @Aladdin

Answer (score 2):

Why is my function being called every time the component renders?
Make sure you aren’t calling the function when you pass it to the component:

```
render() {
 // Wrong: handleClick is called instead of passed as a reference!
 return <button onClick={handleClick()}>Click Me</button>
}
```

Instead, pass the function itself (without parens):

```
render() {
  // Correct: handleClick is passed as a reference!
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
}
```

You can use an arrow function to wrap around an event handler and pass parameters:

```
<button onClick={() => handleClick(id)} />
```